# ansible: escape double curly braces in variable definition

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I have a var in the following form:

```
my_var: "http://somedomain/{{ sometoken }}"
```

When I run the playbook it fails with

> sometoken is undefined

What is the correct syntax for the above variable definition?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work:

```
my_var: "http://somedomain/{% raw -%}{{ sometoken }}{% endraw -%}"
```